# How do I save a sensitive access code safely on localstorage (or other DB)?

Tags: javascript, cordova, encryption, local-storage

I am building an Ionic/Ng Cordova app for which I want to only provide access to certain views when the user has entered an access code correctly.

Upon the first launch of the app, the user is asked to set an access code.

How to use the Access Code to provide access to certain views is another topic, which I will investigate separately.

For now, I am only concerned how to save the Access Code secure on the device, such that users who plug the device with USB to the computer cant read this code or the source code of my app.

I was thinking to write a custom function that transforms the Access Code to an encrypted string, for example:

```
function encryptAccessCode(accessCode) {
   return accessCode.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

I am worried however, that someone can read the source code of my app and then find this function, thus be able to decrypt the encrypted access code string.

Comment: You can use hash method like md5.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as [jcubic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387194/jcubic) says, if you MD5 the original access code on first launch and store this in localstorage, you can compare it to the MD5 of the code entered each time you wish to verify access - [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) will do you nicely.

If you're worried about someone reading your source code, then obfuscate it. You could either use something like [UglifyJS](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) if your build process is automated or do it manually using an [online obfuscator](http://www.jsobfuscate.com/)